# using rhino mocks to create a test case for mocking a webclient method

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I am new to rhino Mocks and I need to write a unit test case for the following method:

```
public string PutFileInArchive(string fileName, string userId, string mimeType, byte[] fileContents, IocContainer container)
    {
        string archiveId;

        try
        {
            IArchiveService _archiveService = container.Resolve<IArchiveService>();
            archiveId = _archiveService.Archive(fileName, mimeType, userId, fileContents);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {             
            throw;
        }

        return archiveId;
    }
```

The above method internally calls a web client method which I need to mock. I created a stub, but I am not sure how to use it. My method is always calling the actual webclient method.

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void Archive_PutFileInArchive_ShouldPut()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\File.txt");
        MemoryFile file = new MemoryFile(reader.BaseStream, "string", "File.txt");

        HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = file;

        var fileContents = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(fileContents, 0, file.ContentLength);

        IFileArchiveService fileArchiveService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFileArchiveService>();

        fileArchiveService.Stub(x => x.Archive("File.txt", "text/plain", "webuser1", fileContents)).Repeat.Once().Return("12345");

        Archive archive = new Archive();
        string fileid = archive.PutFileInArchive("File.txt", "webuser1", "text/plain", fileContents, container);

        Assert.AreEqual("12345", fileid);
    }
```

Please let me know how to use mocks in this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is calling the actual webclient method because the actual webclient is registered in container as an implementation of `IFileArchiveService`.

To use the stub instead, you need to put `fileArchiveService` into `container` as an implementation of `IFileArchiveService` before calling `archive.PutFileInArchive()`
e.g.

```
container.RegisterInstance<IFileArchiveService>(fileArchiveService);
string fileid = archive.PutFileInArchive("File.txt", "webuser1", "text/plain", fileContents, container);
```

Actually, I'd suggest to use different containers for testing and for the application.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Stepaniuk. That fixed it.